How to design a custom openai gym environment to carry out 5G resource slicing?
PROBLEM AT HAND: I have a resource (Bandwidth) of B Hz. I have to distribute the bandwidth B to users as per their requirements. For instance, voice calls would require some amount of bandwidth while video calls would require some amount of bandwidth. Virtual reality applications and Industrial IoT would require more bandwidth than the above two cases. The fraction of bandwidth out of total bandwidth B that I can assign are as follows: [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0]. That is to say, anyone among the above fractions can be assigned.
For this purpose, I am designing a Reinforcement Learning Agent Using Deep Q Learning consisting of a neural network with two inputs, namely Quality of Service Satisfaction and Percentage of Resource Utilization, and eleven outputs representing a value from
[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0].
The output indicates $ y_{ij} $, the fraction of bandwidth allocated to the link between $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ user. We have to determine $y_{ij}$, that is the optimal bandwidth allocated to each link such that the quality of service satisfaction is high as well as the percentage utilization and the summation of bandwidth does not exceed the total bandwidth allocated.
There are $m$ such links. And each link is allocated bandwidth depending upon its requirement.
The Quality of Service Satisfaction is given by:
$$
\varrho\left(r_{i j}\right)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-\eta\left(r_{i j}-r^{\min }\right)}}
$$
Where $r_{ij}$ is given by:
$$
r_{i j}=y_{i j} B \log _{2}\left(1+\gamma_{i j}\right)
$$
The instantaneous data rate $r_{i j}$ can be computed from the signal-to-interference-plus-noise ratio $\gamma_{i j}$.
$r^{\mathrm{min}}$ is the minimum rate requirement of user $i$.
The system satisfaction on average data rate in slice $m$ is defined as the sum of the data rates of individual users and is determined by
$$
\varrho\left(r_{m}\right)=\frac{1}{I_{m}} \sum_{i=1}^{I_{m}} \varrho\left(r_{i j}\right)
$$
The Percentage Resource utilization function can be calculated as
$$
\Psi=\frac{U}{B}
$$
where $U$ denotes the fraction of resource used and $B$ is the resource allocated.
MARKOV DECISION PROCESS FORMULATION:

State(s): The state of the $m$ th slice at time step $t$ is defined as the QoS satisfaction of the $m$ th slice, the resource utilization of the $m$ th slice

The overall reward, $R(s, a)$, can be defined as


$$
R(s, a)=\alpha \cdot \varrho(s, a)+\beta \cdot \Psi(s, a)
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants that denote the importance of $\mathrm{QoS}$ satisfaction and resource utilization, respectively.
MY QUESTION:

How should I design the custom gym environment?

I am planning to design the environment such that it takes Quality of Service Satisfaction and Percentage of Resource Utilization as the input and the fraction of bandwith allocated $y_{ij}$ as the output.
But I have to determine the optimum $y_{ij}$ not just for a single link but a set of links.
Also I have to compute the average Quality of Service Satisfaction and Percentage of Resource Utilization taking all the links into account. Suppose the are four links, then how will the input and the output account for all the four links all at once? (Because the output as per my current design consists of 11 nodes, which correspond to each link.) Do I need to design the Neural Network such that there are (4x2) inputs and (4x11) outputs? Then how should I design the reward function?
How should I design the custom OpenAI Gym environment based on this template taking all the above considerations into account?
After designing the environment I will be using the following code for training:
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=2500)
        self.learning_rate=0.001
        self.epsilon=1
        self.max_eps=1
        self.min_eps=0.01
        self.eps_decay = 0.001/3
        self.gamma=0.9
        self.state_size= state_size
        self.action_size= action_size
        self.epsilon_lst=[]
        self.model = self.buildmodel()

    def buildmodel(self):
        model=Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
        return model

    def add_memory(self, new_state, reward, done, state, action):
        self.memory.append((new_state, reward, done, state, action))

    def action(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() > self.epsilon:
            return np.random.randint(0,4)
        return np.argmax(self.model.predict(state))

    def pred(self, state):
        return np.argmax(self.model.predict(state))

    def replay(self,batch_size):
        minibatch=random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
        for new_state, reward, done, state, action in minibatch:
            target= reward
            if not done:
                target=reward + self.gamma* np.amax(self.model.predict(new_state))
            target_f= self.model.predict(state)
            target_f[0][action]= target
            self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)

        if self.epsilon > self.min_eps:
            self.epsilon=(self.max_eps - self.min_eps) * np.exp(-self.eps_decay*episode) + self.min_eps

        self.epsilon_lst.append(self.epsilon)

    def load(self, name):
        self.model.load_weights(name)

    def save(self, name):
        self.model.save_weights(name)

